# Derive the Expected Value For Maximum Likelyhood Estimators of Mean and Standard Deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

I'm working through Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning. On Page 27 he derives the expressions for the maximum likelihood estimators of the mean and standard deviation for a Gaussian distribution:

$\mu_{ML} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n$
$\sigma^2_{ML} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu_{ML})^2$

He then goes on calculate expectation values of those same quantities

$\mathbb{E}\left[\mu_{ML}\right]=\mu$
$\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma^2_{ML}\right] = \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)\sigma$

How do you derive the expected values for these quantities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
$$
\mathbb{E}[\hat{\mu}] = \mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i =\frac{1}{n}\sum \mathbb{E}X_i=\frac{n}{n}\mu = \mu.
$$

2. Recall that if $X_1,..,X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then 
   $$
   \frac{\sum (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{(n-1)},
   $$
   hence, 
   $$
   \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sum (X_i - \hat{\mu})^2}{n}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\frac{\sum (X_i - \hat{\mu})^2}{\sigma^2}\right] = \frac{\sigma^2(n-1)}{n}.
   $$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more mechanical approach for computing $E[\sigma_{ML}^2]$ that you'd see in a standard stats textbook:

$$E[\sigma_{ML}^2] = \frac{1}{n}E[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2]=\frac{1}{n}(E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 - 2X_i \bar X + \bar X^2])$$

$$E[\sigma_{ML}^2]=\frac{1}{n}(E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2] - 2E[\bar X\sum_{i=1}^nX_i] + nE[\bar X^2]) = \frac{1}{n}(E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2] - 2nE[\bar X^2] + nE[\bar X^2])$$

Where we use: $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i = n\bar X$. Now we have:

$$E[\sigma_{ML}^2]=\frac{1}{n}(n(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) - nE[\bar X^2])$$

Because $E[X_i^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2 $.

Crucial step:

$E[\bar X^2] = Var(\bar X) + E[\bar X]^2 = Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i) + \mu^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2) + \mu^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$

Where we used the fact that the $X_is$ are independent. Back to $\sigma_{ML}^2$:

$$E[\sigma_{ML}^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2 - n\frac{\sigma^2}{n} - n\mu^2 = \frac{(n-1)\sigma^2}{n}$$

Note that if you don't want to use the trick $E[\bar X^2] = Var(\bar X) + E[\bar X]^2$ and be more mechanical in your approach:

$$E[\bar X^2] = \frac{1}{n^2}E[(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)^2] = \frac{1}{n^2}E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 + \sum_{i \not = j}^nX_iX_j] = \frac{1}{n^2}(E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2] + \sum_{i \not = j}^nE[X_i]E[X_j])$$

By independence of $X_i$ and $X_j$.

$$E[\bar X^2] = \frac{1}{n^2}(n(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) + n(n-1)(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)) = \frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2 + n^2\mu^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2$$